# add element to std::list in multi thread without mutex for c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdlist

for current code, output will show different ml size. I'm confusing for that this program doesn't crash and multi threads try to change list in list_thread_safe. how does std::list handle this in c++? thanks firstly.

(uncomment code about mutex, it will get same ml size.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <list>
#include <mutex>
#include <algorithm>

std::mutex list_mutex; 
class list_thread_safe {
public:
    list_thread_safe() {
        std::cout<<"construct a list thread safe"<<std::endl;
    }

    ~list_thread_safe() {
        std::cout<<"destruct a list thread safe"<<std::endl;

    }

    void add_to_list(int new_v) {
        // std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(list_mutex);

        // add 10 elements to list 
        l.push_back(new_v);    
        l.push_back(new_v);  
        l.push_back(new_v);    
        l.push_back(new_v);     
        l.push_back(new_v);    
        l.push_back(new_v);  
        l.push_back(new_v);    
        l.push_back(new_v); 
        l.push_back(new_v);    
        l.push_back(new_v);  
    }
    std::list<int> l;

};

void add1_times(list_thread_safe& lts,int thread_num, int n) {
    for (int i=0; i< n ; i++) {
        lts.add_to_list(i);
    }
    std::cout<<"thread num "<<thread_num<<" done "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"thread list size: "<<lts.l.size()<<std::endl;

}
int main(){
    list_thread_safe ml;
    std::vector<std::thread> ths;
    int thread_num = 10;
    int add_num = 20;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < thread_num; i++)
    {
      printf("%d ", i);
      ths.push_back(std::thread(std::bind(add1_times, std::ref(ml), i, add_num)));
    }

    std::for_each(ths.begin(), ths.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));
    std::cout<<"ml size:"<<ml.l.size()<<std::endl;

}
```

Comment: if you have a race condition (two threads writing to same memory) you program has undefined behaviour, `std::list` does not handle this at all

Comment: Your code without mutex therefore contains _undefined behavior_. Asking why undefined behavior has some particular effect is senseless.

Answer (score 0):

*"...how does std::list handle this..."*

`std::list` is not thread safe.  It is safe to read a `std::list` on more than one thread. 
 But it is not safe to have multiple threads modifying the list, or one thread modifying the list and multiple readers.

Comment: FYI you can use `>` to add a quote

Comment: " It is safe to read a std::list on more than one thread. " Thats not the complete story! If you add data from one thread and try to read from a second one, you have to do synchronization with atomics, mutex, ... The compiler did not know that another thread is reading data from a first thread! It is UB!

Comment: @Klaus you seem to have not read the rest of the paragraph.

Comment: How I can have a list with multiple readers which is not written from one before? I can not see any use case where a list is created ( at minimum constructor was called ) and another thread can read the data without any sync in between.